# IndexedDB state corrupted by .count() after restating the browser

Tags: javascript, count, safari, indexeddb

With a database created, If I execute a `.count()` on an objectstore or an index after restarting Safari (Safari 13.1), it somehow blocks the database and it fails on the next 'readwrite' operation, this doesn't happen in Chrome.

In the example code below, once the page is loaded it creates a database and executes a count (it works correctly), and you can add elements to the objectstore. If you close the browser and open it again the count is executed, but you can no longer insert more elements. Transactions are 'abort'ed.

If the `.count()` is executed a few seconds later instead of just on the 'success' handler (e.g. 5 seconds after loading the page) then it doesn't 'block' the database and everything works. Another alternative that works is doing `.getAll()` and get the `.length` of the result and that works, so that means that the database is accessible.

What happens? What can I do to call `.count()` just at the beginning?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bug indexes corrupted by count() after restart</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="clear-btn">Clear</button>
<button id="insert-not-working">Insert should not work after restarting Safari</button>

<script>
  document.getElementById('clear-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    db.close();
    indexedDB.deleteDatabase('bug');
    console.log('Database deleted, reload the page to start again');
  });
  document.getElementById('insert-not-working').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    console.log('trying to insert');
    const obj1 = await store({created: new Date()}).catch(console.error);
    console.log('Object stored', obj1);
    console.log('Object inserted, should see an error if you have relaunched Safari');
  });

  let db, created = false;
  const dbrequest = indexedDB.open('bug');
  dbrequest.addEventListener('error', console.error);
  dbrequest.addEventListener('blocked', console.error);
  dbrequest.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', (e) => {
    const db = e.target.result;
    const objs = db.createObjectStore('objectstore', {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true});
    console.log('Database did not exist, we just created it');
  });
  dbrequest.addEventListener('success', (e) => {
    db = e.target.result;
    db.addEventListener('error', console.error);
    db.addEventListener('abort', console.error);
    db.addEventListener('versionchange', console.log);
    db.addEventListener('close', console.error);

    console.log('Database exists, now you can insert the objects');

    // This doesn't work
    count().then(n => console.log('This is the problematic count', n));

    // It does work if we call the count later
    // setTimeout(() => count().then(n => console.log('This is not a problematic count', n)), 5000);
  });

  function count() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const objectStore = db.transaction('objectstore', 'readonly').objectStore('objectstore');
      const request = objectStore.count();
      request.addEventListener('success', (e) => resolve(e.target.result));
      // It works if instead we did with getAll().length
      // const request = objectStore.getAll();
      // request.addEventListener('success', (e) => resolve(e.target.result.length));
      request.addEventListener('error', reject);
    });
  }

  function store(obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const transaction = db.transaction('objectstore', 'readwrite');
      const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('objectstore');
      const request = objectStore.put(obj);
      request.addEventListener('success', (e) => obj.id = e.target.result);
      transaction.addEventListener('complete', () => resolve(obj));
      transaction.addEventListener('abort', (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.error(`Error storing ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`, e);
        reject(e);
      });
      request.addEventListener('error', reject);
    });
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried not relying on the global database variable and connecting and disconnecting as needed

Comment: Hi Josh. No, I haven't. Is that recommended? I will be firing quite a few things inside IndexedDB and I thought that it's not logical to have to open the connection to the database every time (what I do now is have the connection open and just open transactions). In any case I don't understand how can I do .getAll() and it works, but .count() is the one that “blocks” the database. If it's recommended to open the connection every time one wants to do a transaction I would appreciate a link to some resources explaining.

Comment: was suggesting it because having to change your code usually reveals the problem, i was suggesting a specific change that afterward would highlight why one way works and the other does not

Comment: In fact, it does work (at least from what I've tested). But I don't understand, I've been playing some time (and to ask this question I invested quite some time trying to find what the bug was in my app), and I cannot comprehend why it doesn't work with a global `let db`, and what's the difference between `.count()` and `.getAll()`. Thank you in any case for pointing it out.

Comment: it is a complicated thing that has to do with asynchronous code that takes a lot of explanation, that is kind of why you're not getting a quick answer (i think)